# Calendar Events adding a foreign Unique Id

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

We can create the Calendar Event, but we need to add our CRM unique Id so we can find all the Calendar Events associated. We have looked at Extended Properties but are looking for an example. 
Thank you, Tim:

Currently, we create an event using the below:

```
// Add the event.
            Event createdEvent = await graphClient.Me.Events.Request().AddAsync(new Event
            {
                Subject = Resource.Event + guid.Substring(0, 8),
                Location = location,
                Attendees = attendees,
                Body = body,
                Start = startTime,
                End = endTime
            });
```

If we could add our own "Extended Property" we would do it here "CalenderEventCRMCaseID = CRMCaseId" and then we could easily query to get all Calendar Events where CRMCaseId = "xxxxxxx". 
Vr, Tim:

Comment: Could you describe what you're looking for in more detail? Samples are easy to come up with but guessing what your stack, language and dev environment is a lot harder. :)

Comment: Thank you, we are using MVC 5, C#, Microsoft Graph Library v1.2.1. Our CRM has an Unique ID for each "CRM Case", we would like to add this "CRM Case ID" to the Event that we create. This would be a one to many relationship (CRM CASE ID to Calendar Event).

Comment: Mr LaFleur, you mentioned samples are easy to come up with - can you point me it the direction where I can possible see an example of this scenario? Vr, Tim:

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET samples are [located here](https://github.com/search?q=aspnet%20sample%20user:microsoftgraph&type=Repositories). There isn't one that covers [Extended Properties](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/extended-properties-overview) specifically but the [Snippets project](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample) should provide a good starting point.

In general, you'll need to create an `EventSingleValueExtendedPropertiesCollectionPage` object and add your properties to it (based on your description, I'm assuming single-value is what you're looking for). You then pass that along by assigning it to `SingleValueExtendedProperties` like so:

```
// Add the event.
Event createdEvent = await graphClient.Me.Events.Request().AddAsync(new Event
{
    Subject = Resource.Event + guid.Substring(0, 8),
    Location = location,
    Attendees = attendees,
    Body = body,
    Start = startTime,
    End = endTime,
    SingleValueExtendedProperties = extendedPropertiesCollectionPage
});
```

Comment: My problem is that while using Microsoft Graph Library as stated above is good, I can not make the connection between how this works from
Microsoft Graph Snippets Sample for ASP.NET 4.6 and https://github.com/microsoftgraph/uwp-csharp-snippets-rest-sample/tree/15c576b3ec504e697f2af2266d0aa59d498474ef/O365-UWP-Unified-API-Snippets/Extensions. Vr, Tim:

Comment: That sample is for UWP (i.e. native Windows app) and, as far as I can tell, is making direct REST calls (i.e. not using an SDK). Are you building a native or ASP.NET app?

Comment: We are building a web application using MVC 5 C# - I only point to that UWP as it has the JSON example, but this is not migrated into Graph v1.2.1 Library we are using - basically just like the Snippets Example for ASP.NET. Vr, Tim:

Comment: If we could get this working in the Snippets Example using Microsoft Graph v1.2.1 (latest version), we would be able to get it to work in our solution.

Comment: Ultimately, GET /me/calendars/{id}?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq '{id_value}') is what we are attempting to accomplish and your right about using SingleValueExtenedProperties; just how to we use the Microsoft Graph Library to add our "id_value".